# Rails 4: How to refresh a div with Ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm currently trying to use ajax to refresh a partial with new data.

I basically have a page which shows one post and a next button which should pull another random post.

**random.html.slim**

```
.page-header
  h2 = link_to "Next", random_path(post_id: @post.id), :remote => true, method: :post
.random-container
  =render partial: 'random_post'
```

**_random_post.html.slim**

```
table
  tr
    td
      h3= @post.author
      p= @post.text
```

**pages_controller.rb**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def random
    id = params[:post_id]
    if id
      @post = Post.where("id != ?", id).order("RAND()").first
    else
      @post = Post.order("RAND()").first
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json
    end
  end
```

**random.coffee.erb**

```
$(".random-container").html("<%= j(render :partial => 'random_post' ) %>")
```

I can't really wrap my head around what I am missing right now to make it work. Hopefully someone can help me! Thx!

Comment: You're missing the JavaScript that actually makes the AJAX call.

Comment: I thought rails does that automatically...

Comment: In your log, is it making the request as JS - it should say something like `Processing by PagesController#random as JS`

Comment: Hmmm... you may have something there. Ignore my first comment.  Does `random_path` work, is it in your routes?  I suspect it should be something like `random_page_path`?

Comment: Next thing to check would be your `respond_to` block.  Try sticking a `format.js` in there.

Comment: Yup it says Processing by PagesController#random as JS

Comment: Yes this is my route: match 'random', to: 'pages#random', via: [:get, :post]

Comment: I put a format.js in there but still doesn't work ... maybe I missed passing the post variable somewhere?

Comment: ah but now the log says that it rendered random.html.slim and _random_post.html.slim after I click next ... but the data still doesn't update

Comment: I checked the HTTP response with firebug and it gives the right html with the new random data ... but it won't replace the old one

Comment: Should I be able to find the random.js file through firebug? Because I can't find it anywhere...